# What is the default value for a Chrome extension background page's "persistent" property?

Tags: google-chrome-extension

A Chrome extension's manifest file has a "persistent" property for its background page. It seems that [Chrome extension API doc](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/mv2/background_pages/) does not explicitely state the default value for the property; the doc simply states that "'persistent' should be specified as false". I would like to know the default value when the property is not specified in a manifest file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is `true` by default for extensions ([source](https://source.chromium.org/chromium/chromium/src/+/master:extensions/common/manifest_handlers/background_info.cc;l=84;drc=2ac64302ae161cd6b5e4b1254497bdf5fd6d3415)), which is why the documentation urges you to specify `false` explicitly when you don't really need persistency.